# Performing Operations On Azure Database

Tags: database, azure

I have a database hosted on Azure. I have an MVC 4 website were users log in and interact with the database. I need something that I can use to traverse through a table in my database, check for certain conditions and then make the required changed to my database. What framework or coding language could I use to achieve this? My hope is that I could have this script run continually or at certain time intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of achieving this and they all depend on your need for scale/resources/etc of this script.

You can code the job in whatever language (including batch if you utilize [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx) or some such)

You can schedule the job to run anywhere you want, including a machine in your office, data center, etc.

You can utilize newly released Aditi's job scheduler (it's free, called Scheduler, and is available in Azure app store)

Comment: How would I go about doing it in java? Could I run the java file on azure?

Comment: I'm sure you could, as long as you install the runtime ahead of time. It's just a windows vm (if you use the Azure's Cloud Services) or it could be a Linux box if you use Azure's IAAS (VM's)